# Why are my Stackdriver Google Pub/Sub subscription/pull_request_count metric alerts broken?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver

I have some alerts set up in Stackdriver to warn me if there are no pull requests for Pub/Sub subscriptions (implying that all my servers are down or broken). However, I noticed these alerts stopped working.

When I pull up the alert in Stackdriver, the Metric is highlighted in red. If I try to set up another alert with the `subscription/pull_request_count` metric, it's not listed. The metric is also listed in the [Pub/Sub monitoring docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_exp), so I'd expect that it's valid.

How can I get this alert working again, or if for some reason this is no longer valid, is there another way to ensure that there are active subscribers at all times?

[image: Broken subscription/pull_request_count target]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/pull_request_count` is still the correct name for this metric. The red metric is an indication of missing data. It looks like something is wrong with the underlying data for your project. Can you open a ticket with Google Cloud support and provide your project ID information so we can investigate further? Please reference this Stackoverflow question in your ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I'll open a ticket. FYI in case this happens to other people, my subscriptions weren't running before and now that they've been collecting data for half a day, I can see data in my existing alerts. However the metric is still red in the UI even after I opened it in a fresh incognito window, and I can't use the metric in new conditions. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505585/how-can-i-get-an-alert-via-stackdriver-when-there-are-no-clients-pulling-from-a) I have is if there's a better way to set up an alert for when there are no pull requests.