# How can I get a reliable alert via Stackdriver when there are no clients pulling from a Pub/Sub subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I currently have some alerts set up to report when `subscription/pull_request_count` is 0. However, in a [similar question about that metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486758/why-are-my-stackdriver-google-pub-sub-subscription-pull-request-count-metric-ale), I found that metrics and alerting break once there is no data, which I believe happens when there are no subscriptions.

My intent is to figure out if my servers have stopped pulling messages. There are 2 scenarios I have in mind where the details are important.

1. Even if there are no messages being published, I want to know if I'm no longer pulling from a subscription to make sure things are working properly.
2. In the event that a ton of unacknowledged messages are queued up just because I pulled them but didn't ack them (e.g. a partner API was down), I don't want this alert to be triggered

Besides using `subscription/pull_request_count` as a condition, which won't work when no data is coming in (at least after a while), how can I set up an alert that notifies me that there no clients pulling from a Pub/Sub subscription?

Comment: Do you really want to check if there are no clients pulling from a Pub/Sub subscription, or do you just want to check if there are undelivered messages because there is no client pulling from the subscription (no client => undelivered messages)?

Comment: Good question. My intent is to figure out if my servers have stopped pulling messages. There are 2 scenarios I have in mind where the details are important. 1) Even if there are no messages being published, I want to know if I'm no longer pulling from a subscription to make sure things are working properly. 2) In the even that a ton of unacknowledged messages are queued up just because I pulled them but didn't ack them (e.g. a partner API was down), I don't want this alert to be triggered.

Comment: Ok, so based on your 2 scenarios, you sadly can't use another metric like `num_undelivered_messages`. You should include these use-cases in your question because there are very relevant! Anyway, it seems that `subscription/pull_request_count` is the metric you want to use here. Have you found why this metric does not generate data sometimes? Could you clarify what "*alerting break once there is no data*" means? Is the alert triggered? How does your alert is configured now? Please add these information to your question, it may help other people to find out what is going on.

Comment: I've added these examples to the question. For details on alerting breaking, see the link in my question to a recent question I posted, where GCP support mentioned the metric meant there is missing data.

Comment: You cannot create the alert via the Web UI, but could you create it via the command-line?

Comment: For the other question, I had created the alert a while back, and after manually observing that I had no subscribers, I went back to check on it and it was red, and all the charts had an error saying there was no data, and I couldn't recreate the same alert.

Comment: Why don't you use `is absent` as the policy condition instead of `is under 1`? Minimum seems to be 3 min though.

Comment: “subscription/pull_request_count” seems to be the one you want to use. I am not aware of a better way, perhaps you could create custom alerts via some custom health check code, however I would wait for the full investigation in regards to the internal case you created that might shed more light.

Comment: @GuillemXercavins that sounds like it might be what I need _in addition_ to checking to see if it `is under 1`. In some cases I think I get a 0, but in others or maybe after it's been a little while, it seems like the data just disappears. Unfortunately, due to the issue I'm having in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486758/why-are-my-stackdriver-google-pub-sub-subscription-pull-request-count-metric-ale), I can't currently add new alerts with `subscription/pull_request_count` so I can't try this out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to be alerted when there are no pull message operations you'll have to use the [`subscription/pull_request_count`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub) metric. If, after some time, the metric is dropped instead of reporting 0 pulls you can use two conditions: `is absent for 3 minutes` OR `is below 1 for 1 minute`:

[image]

However, the problem here is that the UI filters out all unused resources and metrics (for the past 6 weeks). While this greatly eases out setting alerts and browsing through metrics for running operations it requires a different approach to create new alerts before a system is in production. The easiest solution is to make a dummy subscription and pull messages so that the metric appears.

But you can still use the Stackdriver Monitoring API to set them up (I actually tested this with a Spanner metric in a workspace with no instances for the last few months). Keep in mind that the alerting policies API is in [Beta](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/#alerting-policies) so it's subject to non-backwards-compatible changes.

I'd recommend to start by inspecting an already existing policy with [`projects.alertPolicies/list`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies/list) and see how the [`AlertPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#AlertPolicy) body is constructed.

Then you can set some initial variables:

```sh
TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
PROJECT=$(gcloud config get-value project 2>\dev\null)
SUBSCRIPTION=PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
CHANNEL=NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
```

In my case I am monitoring only a specific Pub/Sub subscription throughout the example and I already had a notification channel (for my email). As you also have an existing policy you can get the notification channel ID [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.notificationChannels/list).

With `projects.alertPolicies/create` you can create the new alert policy:

```sh
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  "https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/$PROJECT/alertPolicies" \
  -d @alert.json
```

where `alert.json` is (replace the variables as needed):

```js
{
  "displayName": "no-pull-alert",
  "combiner": "OR",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "conditionAbsent": {
        "filter": "metric.type=\"pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/pull_request_count\" resource.type=\"pubsub_subscription\" resource.label.\"project_id\"=\"$PROJECT\" resource.label.\"subscription_id\"=\"$SUBSCRIPTION\"",
        "duration": "180s",
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        },
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE"
          }
        ]
      },
      "displayName": "Pull requests absent for $PROJECT, $SUBSCRIPTION"
    },
    {
      "conditionThreshold": {
        "filter": "metric.type=\"pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/pull_request_count\" resource.type=\"pubsub_subscription\" resource.label.\"project_id\"=\"$PROJECT\" resource.label.\"subscription_id\"=\"$SUBSCRIPTION\"",
        "comparison": "COMPARISON_LT",
        "thresholdValue": 1,
        "duration": "60s",
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        },
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE"
          }
        ]
      },
      "displayName": "Pull requests are 0 for $PROJECT, $SUBSCRIPTION"
    }
  ],
  "documentation": {
    "content": "**ALERT**\n\nNo pull message operations",
    "mimeType": "text/markdown"
  },
  "notificationChannels": [
    "projects/$PROJECT/notificationChannels/$CHANNEL"
  ],
  "enabled": true
}
```

Briefly, you don't need to pass policy or condition IDs as those will be populated by the API. Use `OR` as the combiner (*policy violates when ANY condition is met*) to trigger the alert when the metric is either absent (`conditionAbsent`) or below 1 (`conditionThreshold`). And, of course, you can modify parameters to better suit your use case, display names, descriptions, etc.

[image]

Comment: I used this in production and ended up getting a few false alarms within a few days - each lasting a few seconds, which was triggered by the `is absent for 3 minutes` rule, even though the data wasn't absent at all. I've updated absent condition to use a 4 minute window instead and haven't gotten any false alarms since.

Comment: I've recently switched to using the Google Cloud Java JDK, and it uses `StreamingPull` instead of `Pull` with constant polling. While this is better and more efficient behind the scenes, it makes things harder to monitor because there won't be any API requests except at app startup, or when messages come in. Unfortunately, this means that on a subscription that _doesn't have regular activity_, the best metric we can use is the age of the oldest message, so we won't find out if there are no subscribers until a message is sent.